# How can I set an oracle variable to null?

Tags: oracle, variables, stored-procedures, null

How to set a variable in oracle procedure to null? I want to do this because the variable is in a cursor, so needs to set to null for every iteration. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Just assign the "value" null:

```
variable := null;
```

Comment: @ArunVijay - for varchar2-variables it could be written shorter: `variable := '';`